# Format laravel number with if condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code to calculate the total price of a profit order and it works just fine.

```
{{ number_format($order->quantity * $order->product->price, 0) }}
```

I want to add an extra price field for, for example a license price so if the user selected a license as well the price of that should be added to the code above but as not all products have a license price I need to make an if statement so that the price can be sum to this price only if the license price exist.

How can I do that?

PS: working with laravel 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@if( ! empty($order->license_price)) 
    {{ number_format($order->quantity * $order->product->price + $order->license_price, 0)}}
@else
   {{ number_format($order->quantity * $order->product->price, 0) }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary operator:

```
number_format($order->quantity * $order->product->price + empty($order->license) ? 0 : $order->license, 0)
```